# Implementing an interface with interface members

Tags: c#, interface

What is the proper way to implement an interface that has its own interface members?  (am I saying that correctly?)  Here's what I mean:

```
public Interface IFoo
{
    string Forty { get; set; }
    string Two { get; set; }
}

public Interface IBar
{
    // other stuff...

    IFoo Answer { get; set; }
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public string Forty { get; set; }
    public string Two { get; set; }
}

public class Bar : IBar
{
    // other stuff

    public Foo Answer { get; set; } //why doesnt' this work?
}
```

I've gotten around my problem using explicit interface implementation, but I'm wondering if there is a better way?

Comment: Could you please show the code with the explicit interface implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to use generics to be able to do what you want.

```
public interface IFoo
{
    string Forty { get; set; }
    string Two { get; set; }
}

public interface IBar<T>
    where T : IFoo
{
    // other stuff...

    T Answer { get; set; }
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public string Forty { get; set; }
    public string Two { get; set; }
}

public class Bar : IBar<Foo>
{
    // other stuff

    public Foo Answer { get; set; }
}
```

This will allow you to provide an interface that says something like, "to implement this interface you must have a property with a public getter/setter of a type that implements `IFoo`."  Without generics you are simply saying that the class has a property with a type of exactly `IFoo`, rather than anything that implements `IFoo`.

Comment: hi, could you please explain why @jstark code does not work while IBar implementation needs an IFoo property and Foo is IFoo !!! thank you.

Comment: @Parsa `IBar` says that you need to have a property that accepts and returns `IFoo`, it doesn't say that it has a property that accepts and returns a `Foo`.  You need to implement interface members *exactly*.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the exact same type as in the interface:

```
public class Bar : IBar 
{ 
    public IFoo Answer { get; set; }   
}
```

Note: `IFoo` instead of `Foo`.

The reason is that the interface defines a contract and the contract says that it must be an `IFoo`.

Think about it:

You have the classes `Foo` and `Foo2`, both implement `IFoo`. According to the contract, instances of both classes can be assigned. Now, if your code was legal, this would somehow break because your class only accepts `Foo`. Explicit interface implementation doesn't change that fact in any way.

Answer (score 0):

IBar has a IFoo field, not a Foo one, do this instead:

```
public class Bar : IBar
{
    // other stuff

    public IFoo Answer { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Foo may extend type IFoo but that isn't what the interface exposes. 
An interface defines a contract and you need to obey the terms of that contract.
So the correct way is to use 
`public IFoo Answer{get;set;}` like others have said.